# Why can't delete a task in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm expecting to delete a task in a App.js array by filtering. But the array keeps the same after clicking the delete button in the Task child component. Even though I'm passing an id as a function attribute.

```
// App.js component

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Tasks);

  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    Tasks.filter((task) => task.id === id);
  };
  
  return (

<TaskComponent
  Tasks={tasks}
  changeTask={changeTask}
  deleteTask={deleteTask}
/>
)

// TaskComponent

type Tasks = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  author_name: string;
  description: string;
  status: number | any;
  priority: number | any;
};

type Props = {
  Tasks: Tasks[];
  changeTask: (tasks: Tasks) => {};
  deleteTask: (tasks: Tasks) => {};
};

const TaskComponent: FC<Props> = ({ Tasks, changeTask, deleteTask }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const { id } = useParams<IdParams>();

  const task = Tasks.find((task) => String(task.id) === id);

  const [status, setStatus] = useState(task?.status);
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState(task?.priority);


  const handleDeleteTask = () => {
    deleteTask({
      ...task,
      id
    });

    history.push("/taskslist");
  };
  
  return (
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="delete" onClick={handleDeleteTask} />
  </form>
  )
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-login-page-tasks-typescript-24-04-eg91s5?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: I'm not familiar with React, but in plain JS, `Array.filter` returns a new array. However, you're not setting the new array to a variable.

Comment: And that's exactly what happens here you are creating a new array and sending it... into the void. Pick it up and set and new state from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tasks prop in TaskComponent should be camelCase
2. TaskComponent - no need to include Component in the name
3. handleDeleteTask correct naming, but what does it do? Call the callback called deleteTask... then... do something with history - not deletion related.

So... what is deleteTask? Do you need to update a state above TaskComponent with a new `Tasks` value for TaskComponent i.e. a selection of tasks which does not include this task in question.

So your issue lies in this:

```
const deleteTask = (id) => {
  Tasks.filter((task) => task.id === id);
};
```

Does filter delete a task? No - ok so maybe you need to map / reduce / filter to create a new reference object without the task you want to delete and update the state in the parent i.e. use `setTasks`

```
const deleteTask = (id) => {
   setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id === id))
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the setter method `setTasks` in order to set the tasks prop on your app like this:

```
const deleteTask = (id) => {
   setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id === id))
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem** :- you filter directly Task List that the problem page is not re-render..

```
 const deleteTask = (id) => {
    Tasks.filter((task) => task.id === id);
 };
```

**Solution** :-

```
const deleteTask = (id) => {
    let newtask = task.filter((task) => task.id !== id);
     setTasks([...newtask]);
 };
```

Comment: You don't really need to make a new of `newTasks` as `filter` already returns a new array.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should really only be passing down the data for one task to the `Task` component. You can do this by using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array of tasks and for each task return a `Task` component with just the props that it needs. If you're using `history` to only display one task the process to get the task using the id from `history` should be done within the `App` component using `filter` rather than within the `Task` component itself.
2. Since `deleteTask` only accepts an id that's all you should be passing to it. At the moment you're passing an object.
3. Within `deleteTask` you should be filtering out all the tasks where their id *doesn't* match the id passed in as an argument.
4. You need to set a new state with the array that `filter` returns.
5. Watch your capitalisation - JS is case-sensitive. For example in `deleteTask` you're trying to `filter` over `Tasks` when you should be filtering over `tasks`.
6. If your dataset of tasks don't have ids I would recommend that you add them in. That way you can use them both as a key on the iterated `Task` components, and as a way to identify which task should be deleted by assigning that id to the delete buttons.

I've written two short examples to cover these points. The first to show how to `map` over the data to produce a series of tasks with the `Task` component, and the second to show how you might use `history` to only show one task.

##### Example one

```js
const { useState } = React;

// For the sake of convenience I'm
// passing in an array of predefined tasks
function App({ data }) {
  
  // And I'm setting state with those tasks
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(data);

  // `filter` returns a new array - you want to filter
  // out (return) all those tasks that don't match the id
  // that you pass in as an argument. You then need to set
  // the state with that new filtered array
  function deleteTask(id) {
    const filtered = tasks.filter(task => {
      return task.id !== id;
    });
    setTasks(filtered);
  };
  
  // `map` over the tasks in state and for each
  // one pass down the relevant data to the
  // `Task` component
  return (
    <main>
      {tasks.map(task => {
        return (
          <Task
            key={task.id}
            data={task}
            deleteTask={deleteTask}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );

}

function Task({ data, deleteTask }) {

  // Call `delete` task with the id from
  // the button's dataset
  function handleDelete(e) {
    deleteTask(Number(e.target.dataset.id));
  }
  
  return (
    <section>
      {data.text}
      <button
        data-id={data.id}
        type="button"
        onClick={handleDelete}
      >Delete
      </button>
    </section>
  );

}

const tasks = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Task 1', status: 'incomplete', priority: 1},
  { id: 2, text: 'Task 2', status: 'incomplete', priority: 2},
  { id: 3, text: 'Task 3', status: 'complete', priority: 3}
];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<App data={tasks} />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

##### Example 2

This mocks the `useHistory` by passing a history object in the `App` props so you can see how you might get only the task that is passed in by id. It uses an additional `useEffect` to show the task state once you delete the task.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// For the sake of convenience I'm
// passing in an array of predefined tasks,
// and a mock history object
function App({ data, history }) {
  
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(data);

  // Getting the id from history
  const { id } = history;

  function deleteTask(id) {
    const filtered = tasks.filter(task => {
      return task.id !== id;
    });
    setTasks(filtered);
  };
  
  // Get only the task that has an id that
  // matches the id from history
  function getTask(id) {
    return tasks.filter(task => task.id === id);
  }

  // An effect to show how the state changes
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);

  // Get the task corresponding to the id from
  // history - `getTask` uses `filter` which returns
  // an array so we can still `map` over the result
  return (
    <main>
      {getTask(id).map(task => {
        return (
          <Task
            key={task.id}
            data={task}
            deleteTask={deleteTask}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );

}

function Task({ data, deleteTask }) {

  // Call `delete` task with the id from
  // the button's dataset
  function handleDelete(e) {
    deleteTask(Number(e.target.dataset.id));
  }
  
  return (
    <section>
      {data.text}
      <button
        data-id={data.id}
        type="button"
        onClick={handleDelete}
      >Delete
      </button>
    </section>
  );

}

const tasks = [
  { id: 1, text: 'Task 1', status: 'incomplete', priority: 1},
  { id: 2, text: 'Task 2', status: 'incomplete', priority: 2},
  { id: 3, text: 'Task 3', status: 'complete', priority: 3}
];

const myHistory = {
  id: 2
};

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<App data={tasks} history={myHistory} />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```